# SQL Server Always Encryption

Tags: sql-server, encryption, privileges, always-encrypted

If I have activated column level encryption, what is the minimum privileges (excluding Connect) a user must have to access the unencrypted (clear text) data from an encrypted column?

| Permission |
| --- |
| References |
| Show Plan |
| Select |
| Update |
| Checkpoint |
| View Definition |
| Execute |
| Alter |
| Control |
| Unmask |

Comment: References,
Show Plan, 
Select, 
Update, 
Checkpoint,
View Definition,
Execute,
Alter,
Control,
Unmask

Comment: Encryption isn't specifically gated by privilege. If the user can select the column, *and* they have the key used for the encryption client-side, they will be able to get the column and decrypt it. Otherwise, they have no access. There is no special "decrypt column" permission or suchlike.

Comment: So, what above statements client can use for encrypted column to access to sensitive data? Or you mean once clients have asymmetric and symmetric key, they can access data use some statements only by key allowed?

Comment: Always Encrypted is *transparent* to clients. That means `SELECT Column FROM Table` and `INSERT Table(Column) SELECT @ParameterValue` will do, whether `Column` is encrypted or not. The connection string must then contain `Column Encryption Setting=Enabled`. See the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/always-encrypted-certificate-store-configure#create-a-client-application-that-works-with-the-encrypted-data). SSMS also has support for passing through simple statements that contain literals, by rewriting these to use parameters in the background.

Comment: Ok, I saw the link, thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

there are three, select, view, but not sure about the third one, the show
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-parameter-encryption-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).